Laravel Nwidart: Giving Error while generating module
Generating file Modules/Page/module.json .............................................. 0ms DONE
Generating file Modules/Page/routes/web.php ........................................... 0ms DONE
Generating file Modules/Page/routes/api.php ........................................... 0ms DONE
Generating file Modules/Page/resources/views/index.blade.php .......................... 0ms DONE
Generating file Modules/Page/resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php  ................ 0ms DONE
Generating file Modules/Page/config/config.php ........................................ 0ms DONE
Generating file Modules/Page/composer.json ............................................ 0ms DONE
Generating file Modules/Page/resources/js/app.js ...................................... 0ms FAIL

ErrorException

file_get_contents(/vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/Support/../Commands/stubs/js/app.stub): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

at vendor/nwidart/laravel-modules/src/Support/Stub.php:106

* @return mixed|string
*/
public function getContents()
{
 $contents = file_get_contents($this->getPath());
 foreach ($this->replaces as $search => $replace) {
 $contents = str_replace('$' . strtoupper($search) . '$', $replace, $contents);
}

I have tried updating the package, trying to found out what causing this error. Module is generated but without service provider files.
